# How can I compare a tuple and a list?

Tags: python

I am creating a program that will open a file that contains a list of a users exam answers and compares them to a tuple that contains the correct answers for the exam. I want the variable "count" to increment with each correct answer. My current problem is that I keep receiving a count of 0 as my score for the exam, even when I have all of the correct answers stored in the userAns list. My program displays the number of answers the user answered correctly and displays the userAns list at the end (just so I can make sure the correct answers have been appended to the list).

```
def main():
    correctAns = ('A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C',
                  'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A')
    userAns = []
    PERFECT = 20
    count = 0
    try:
        fileName = input('Enter the student test data filename: ')
        inFile = open(fileName, 'r')

        for line in inFile:
            fieldList = line.split('\n')
            userAns.append(fieldList)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('The file could not be found.')

    else:

        for i in range(len(correctAns)):
            if correctAns[i] == userAns[i]:
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 0

        if count >= 15:
            print('Congratulations!! You passed the exam.')
        else:
            print('Sorry, you did not pass the exam.')
    print(f'You answered {count} out of {PERFECT} questions correctly.')
    print(userAns)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where am I going wrong in comparing these two sets of answers? I feel like it has something to do with the conditional statement in my for loop.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Enter the student test data filename: answers.txt
Sorry, you did not pass the exam.
You answered 0 out of 20 questions correctly.
[['A', ''], ['C', ''], ['A', ''], ['A', ''], ['D', ''], ['B', ''], ['C', ''], ['A', ''], ['C', ''], ['B', ''], ['A', ''], ['D', ''], ['C', ''], ['A', ''], ['D', ''], ['C', ''], ['B', ''], ['B', ''], ['D', ''], ['A']]
```

Here is a list of user answers to test this (should all be correct):

```
A
C
A
A
D
B
C
A
C
B
A
D
C
A
D
C
B
B
D
A
```

Comment: Since we don't have your student test data file, we can't run your code.  Could you at least include the output (especially the output of `print(userAns)`) to make it possible to reverse-engineer what your script is reading in from that file?  It seems likely that that's actually where your problem is, since your loop seems like it should work fine if `userAns` and `correctAns` have the same shape.

Comment: Have at least tried to debug it ? Like printing the least, or the 2 variables being compared ot understand the problem ? Problem that I can see `line.split('\n')` makes a list, so `userAns` contains lists, whereas `correctAns` contains string, then can't be equal. Guess you meant `strip`

Comment: is not split giving you a list already, should not you be extending the list instead of appending it?

Comment: Why did you decide to make `correctAns ` a tuple?

Comment: I have added a sample output as well as a test file sample that contains the correct answers so if this were to work, it would give me the congrats message as well as telling me i scored 20 out of 20. The prompt I have specifically states that I must use a tuple for the correct answers and lists for the user answers. Azro was correct that I needed to use strip instead of split.

Comment: A suggestion: The loop where you calculate `count` can be replaced with
`count = sum(user == correct for (user, correct) in zip(userAns, correctAns))`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you do not convert file data to a list of answers correctly.

```py
fileName = input('Enter the student test data filename: ')

# add the first char of each line to a list: ['A', 'C', 'A']
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    userAns = [line[0] for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]

count = 0
for actual, expected in zip(userAns, correctAns):
   if actual == expected:
      count += 1
```

I used `if line.strip()` to skip a potential empty last line in input file.

`zip` merges two arrays element by element: `list(zip([1, 2], [3, 4])) => [(1, 3), (2, 4)]`. This makes comparison of expected and user answers a bit easier than using indexes. Your approach looks correct as well though.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Your code is definitely cleaner and more simple. I'm a student so all of my code is a little long and can be confusing but you are right that I did not convert the file to a list correctly! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Samwise for saying to look at print(userAns), I can't believe I didn't notice that I was not eliminating the new line characters from the answer file. Azro was correct. By simply replacing line.split('\n') in line 20 with line.strip('\n'), I was able to compare the correctAns to userAns and get an accurate count. Here is the updated code that works for what I need it to do:

```
def main():
    correctAns = ('A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C',
                  'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A')
    userAns = []
    PERFECT = 20
    COUNT = 0
    try:
        fileName = input('Enter the student test data filename: ')
        inFile = open(fileName, 'r')

        for line in inFile:
            fieldList = line.strip('\n')
            userAns.append(fieldList)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('The file could not be found.')

    else:
        for i in range(len(correctAns)):
            if correctAns[i] == userAns[i]:
                COUNT += 1
            else:
                COUNT += 0

        if COUNT >= 15:
            print('Congratulations!! You passed the exam.')
        else:
            print('Sorry, you did not pass the exam.')
    print(f'You answered {COUNT} out of {PERFECT} questions correctly.')
    print(userAns)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

answers.txt file:

```
A
C
A
A
D
B
C
A
C
B
A
D
C
A
D
C
B
B
D
A
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Enter the student test data filename: answers.txt
Congratulations!! You passed the exam.
You answered 20 out of 20 questions correctly.
['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A']
```